# typescript installs lodash incorrectly

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash

I've been installing lodash with ..

```
typings install dt~lodash --global --save
```

worked perfectly until recently but now i get ..

> Attempted to compile "lodash" as a global module, but it looks like an
>   external module. You'll need to remove the global option to continue.

so i did ..

```
typings install dt~lodash --save
```

which allowed the install to proceed.

But now in my logs I get the error ..

> typings\modules\lodash\index.d.ts(243,1): error TS1316: Global module exports may only appear at top level.

that is a file generated by typings. line 243 looks like ..

```
export as namespace _;
```

Webstorm IDE also gives exactly the same error.

any idea how to fix this? thx

Comment: Same here since today. I had the bad idea to delete and reinstall all my node modules and definition files, and my build is unable to work anymore (was working fine for weeks)... Looks like some library is broken somewhere, but couldn't figure out which one :( Did you find something ?

Comment: unable to help im afraid, for future reference, use npm shrinkwrap to lockdown your npm modules, as for typescript definitions, im a stuck as u

Comment: I think this is related to https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/13338 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force a previous version of the lodash ts definition file to be downloaded, both syntax works for me:

```
{
    "globalDependencies": {
        "lodash": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/lodash/index.d.ts#253e456e3c0bf4bd34afaceb7dcbae282da14066",
    }
}
```

where `253e456e3c0bf4bd34afaceb7dcbae282da14066` is the commit hash code in github,
or

```
{
    "globalDependencies": {
        "lodash": "registry:dt/lodash#4.14.0+20161110215204",
    }
}
```

where `4.14.0+20161110215204` is supposed to be a tagged version, but not sure how it is generated. I found it in the typings/globals/lodash/typings.json file of the last working downloaded .d.ts version.

Answer (score 2):

You can install `lodash` as below also :

```
npm install --save @types/lodash
```

Then, in your .ts file:

Either:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

Or

```
import _ from "lodash";
```

Comment: Ok I finally understand your answer. Many definition files has been updated lately, without any tags or versions, crashing my project. Using typings, do you know if it is possible to reference a specific commit? Something like that does not work      "lodash": "registry:dt/lodash#9e1555c7ff12e04e7de962a22b1d914c4eb32a57"

Comment: nice question kloe